# Fractional quantum Hall effect: is new physics required to understand it?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-hall-effect

Is it true that some of the experimentally observed states in [fractional quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect) are unexplainable by current physics? If so, does this point towards a revision of quantum mechanics, and / or understanding of space-time structure, when conventional physics is applied to understand these states?

Comment: Which states do you find problematic?

Comment: I think that looking at the fractional Hall effect stimulated a lot of research in looking at problems considering topology, topological insulators and related phenomena, but I don’t think that is a considered a ‘revision’ of quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Unexplain**ed** is not the same as unexplain**able**.  It's certainly true that the fractional quantum Hall effect is the subject of active and fascinating research, and that there are aspects of it which are not yet understood. But strongly correlated systems *in general* are very difficult to understand, so I don't think that indicates a need for new physics so much as a need to develop a better understanding of the physics we already have.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the states of FQHE fit in some shape of model, e.g. non abelian states are typically cited to solve most of the problems (e.g. Moore) but also composite fermion theories claim they can classify most of the states (e.g. Jain). If you see this review paper: https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.89.025005 you will notice that there is quite a pletheora of new and old approaches (such as CFT , SUSY, partons and even holography).

What is the difficulty is that in high energy physics you always have a definition of in and out states and scattering interactions, and there is a bias in the community to be able still to talk always in terms of particles, 4 particle interactions are also an exception (e.g beta decay of Fermi). This was also the case in condensed matter before the quantum hall, and it was also the case for superfluids (e.g. cooper pairs).

Here instead the models fits in  between a fluid (imagine here turbulence) and solitons (imagine here lumps of electrons that behave and interact non linearly at low energy together). On top these are n to n interactions (read here the highly correlated / non linear part / chaotic part/ coupled n-body problem), there are border vs bulk effects (read here the topology mentioned above). Therefore a lot of the easy assumptions fail.

It's cool cause is somewhat fundamental, but is hard. The community is rather small and you can throw in quite a lot of math, what you see that is a bit like a forest of trees (the states) and each tree is slightly different. What is lacking maybe is a single large consistent picture that can explain all nuances in a solid manner, but this is also the case in most condensed matter physics where often there isn't a one size fit all model.

These "little bastards" of electrons behave sometimes as fluids sometime as quasi-particles and some times as solitons.

If you want an intuition of why is fundamental, you can do it in terms of analogy (e.g. Laughlin/Tong): you can compare empty space in some precise sense to a superfluid in the sense of a fermi liquid, and in that same analogy fractional quantum hall is a more refined / complex form of superfluid with extra / topological degrees of freedom, i.e. a non fermi liquid.